# Why can CPU memory be specified and allocated during instance creation but not GPU memory on the cloud?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, gpu, cluster-computing, supercomputers

On cloud computing platforms like AWS/Cloud/Slurm you can specify the amount of CPU memory that you want. But you can't do this for GPUs. For example H100 has 80 GB memory and you can't specify additional memory. Why is this?